# Where and how does drupal store the node body in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

I am programatically trying to create a custom node to store some content, which I would like to display on a page.
Following is how I am executing it.

```
    $node = new StdClass();
    $node->name = $value;
    $node->title = $node->name;
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $javascript.$html;
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = $type;
    $node->type = "custom_type";
    $node->created = time();
    node_save($node);
```

I notice that the content I inserted are present in the tables
'field_data_body' and 'field_revision_body'
I try to load the node and get the content

```
   $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
   $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
              ->propertyCondition('type', 'custom_type')
              ->propertyCondition('title', $type)                         
              ->execute();
   if (!empty($entities['node'])) {
        $node = node_load(array_shift(array_keys($entities['node'])));
        $html = $html.$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'];
   }
```

But what puzzles me is how from where is the content being loaded. I deleted the entries in both 'field_data_body' and 'field_revision_body', but the content still gets loaded.

So how does drupal7 save and load the contents of the node body?

Comment: try to empty cache in admin/config/development/performance. don't forget fields taxonomy_index, noe, node_revision.

Comment: Don't forget fields.. what is fields? `taxonomy_index`, `node` and `node_revision` are tables and neither have anything to do with the node bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you emptied out the field_data_body (and revision) table and you are still getting data that can only mean three things:

1. you emptied the wrong table (wrong database or the right database with the wrong prefix)
2. it's still cached (there's a clear cache button on the `admin/config/development/performance` page).
3. You are not using SQL to store your fields. Do you have `mongodb_field_storage` enabled? Something even more exotic?

As for how it gets stored, `node_save` calls `field_attach_insert` (and `node_load` calls `field_attach_load`) which, in turn, calls the field storage module which I presume is `field_sql_storage` and so `field_sql_storage_field_storage_write` writes your database records and `field_sql_storage_field_storage_load` loads them.

Also note that `array_shift(array_keys())` is wrong (`E_STRICT` error: `Only variables should be passed by reference` because array_shift takes a reference and array_keys is not returning by reference. Finally, you should feed your `EntityFieldQuery` code to the coder module to fix the coding standards: at least the code inside the if is indented wrong and the string concat operator (the dot) needs spaces on both sides. It hurts my eyes :)

Comment: I had to put sunglasses when I read the question. `;)`

Comment: Awesome !!It was because if the data being cached by drupal ! Thanks !!